# how to take json format in python

Tags: python, json

I have a json

```
format = [
  {
     "Deskripsi": "Anda baik dalam Bersikap tegas dan menolak hal yang tidak disukai"
  }
]
```

I wrote this script which prints all of the json text:

```
io = StringIO()
json.dump(format,io)
return io.getvalue()
```

How can I take the `"Anda baik dalam Bersikap tegas dan menolak hal yang tidak disukai"` from the json format?

Comment: you know about `json.dumps()`, right?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `format` is not **JSON**. Is a python list containing a dictionary.

You could get what you want by doing:

```
format[0]["Deskripsi"]
```